# Boiling points of v. similar organic molecules

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point, isomers

Given the similarity in formula between pentane ($\small\ce{CH3(CH2)3CH3}$, b.p. 36.2 °C) and neopentane ($\small\ce{C(CH3)4}$, b.p. 9.5 °C), why are their boiling points so different?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Would you be willing to share what level of explanation you are looking for (i.e. what level of chemistry you understand)? Do you want a High School level answer, a General Chemistry level answer, an answer using quantum mechanics, etc.? The more you put into a question like this the better answers you will get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solids and liquids are hold together by cohesion. Intermolecular interactions contributing to cohesion depend on the geometry of the molecules in interaction,too.  Here, *n*-pentane with an elongated molecular structure exhibits a much larger molecular surface as compared to *neo*-pentane of a more sphere-like structure*).  As a result, other criteria kept constant (like the molecular mass), the lesser the molecular surface area of molecules of a substance, the lower the boiling temperature of this substance.

*)True, *neo*-pentane's methyl groups point towards the vertices of a tetrahedron. Actually I recommend to build a molecular model of both compounds and place them side-by-side to see it.